# Equation for Bayesian update with two parameters

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to understand a certain model, but I have no real training in probability. I was wondering whether this is correct...

$$
    P\left( A \mid B, C \right) =
    \frac{ P\left( B \mid A, C \right) P\left(A \right) }
         { \sum_{i=1}^{ n } P \left( B \mid A_i, C \right) P \left( A_i \right) }
$$

...or whether it should rather be:

$$
    P\left( A \mid B, C \right) =
    \frac{ P\left( B \mid A, C \right) P\left(A  \mid C \right) }
         { \sum_{i=1}^{ n } P \left( B \mid A_i, C \right) P \left( A_i\mid C \right) }
$$

...or whether both are just wrong (Clearly it is assumed here that we know $P \left( B \mid A, C \right) $ for all $A$s). I am not sure how to approach finding out whether one is right and if so which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation is correct, since conditioning on the events $A_i$ and $C$ gives:

\begin{equation}
P(A \mid B,C) = \frac{P(B \mid A,C) P(A,C)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(B \mid A_i,C) P(A_i,C)}
\end{equation}

Now, using that $P(A,C) = P(A \mid C)P(C)$, and canceling the $P(C)$ in numerator and denominator, we arrive at the second equation.

Comment: So if we know that $ P \left( A_i \right) $ and $ P \left( C \right) $ are independent for all $A$s, then the first formula is correct as well?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, since then we would have $P(A_i \mid C) = P(A_i)$ and $P(A \mid C) = P(A)$.